# How to make a path/subpath configurable?

Tags: python, filepath

I have a python program where I am calling a folder container some tests that i run. the path is hard coded like this:

```
test_path = src/test/unittest
```

But imagine I want to move the folder `unittest` to another location, but i still want the program to know the path to call `unittest`. How do I make the path configurable?

I tried doing something like this:

```
dataDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.basename(__file__))
testConfigFile = os.path.join(dataDir, 'unittest')
```

But when i call `testConfigFile`, it directly goes to unittest, without going through src/test/

Comment: define an environment variable with a default: `os.getenv("TEST_PATH","src/test/unitest")`

Comment: You insert the `PATH` to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or you append it using sys.path

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre correct me if i am wrong, but if i do it the way u have mentioned, the `unittest` folder still has to be inside `src/test` right? My question is: I want to move the sub folder 'unittest' outside the above mentioned path. . but i want the program to recognize `unittest` when called.

For eg: instead of src/test/unittest, i am moving the folder to rsc/unittest. But when i call unittest, the program should know the path and call it

Answer (score 1):

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('.', True):
  if files.count('unittest'):
    dataDir=root
```